# Serializing collection of objects to JSON and XML

Tags: java, xml, json, web-services, jaxb

I have a simple web service that consumes and produces some beans in XML and JSON formats. Then I have a bean that contains a collection of objects:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Company {

  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "addresses")
  @XmlElement(name = "address")
  private Collection<Address> addresses;
  ...
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address{
  private String street;
  private String city;
  private String country;
  ...
}
```

After serialization I have this XML:

```
<company>
 <addresses>
   <address>
      <street>Testowa 1A</street>
      <city>Warszawa</city>
      <country>Polska</country>
   </address>
   <address>
      <street>Testowa 2A</street>
      <city>Warszawa</city>
      <country>Polska</country>
   </address>
 </addresses>
</company>
```

which is correct and JSON:

```
"company" : {
  "addresses": {
     "address": [ {"street": "Testowa 1A", "city": "Warszawa", "country": "Polska"} ],
     "address": [ {"street": "Testowa 2A", "city": "Warszawa", "country": "Polska"} ]
  }
}
```

The problem is with JSON. The notation of the serialized collection can not be accepted by my web service users. They require something like that:

```
"company" : {
  "addresses": [
     {"street": "Testowa 1A", "city": "Warszawa", "country": "Polska"},
     {"street": "Testowa 2A", "city": "Warszawa", "country": "Polska"}
  ]
}
```

If I remove `@XmlElementWrapper` I will have JSON that I need but then my XML will be incorrect (no 'addresses' tag):

```
<company>
  <address>
     <street>Testowa 1A</street>
     <city>Warszawa</city>
     <country>Polska</country>
  </address>
  <address>
    <street>Testowa 2A</street>
     <city>Warszawa</city>
     <country>Polska</country>
  </address>
</company>
```

Any idea how to meet these two requirements?

Comment: sorry copy/paste exception check now

Comment: Show us `Address`. What JAXB annotations do you use on it?

Comment: <company>
<address>...</address>
<address>...</address>
</company>

Comment: oki, give me a sec I just double check

Comment: I have added Address class to the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) itself doesn't cover how to convert objects to/from JSON. This means that the answer will depend on what JSON-binding implementation you are using that is currently interpreting the JAXB annotations.

In [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) we offer JSON-binding a runtime property called `JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME` that enables the behaviour you are looking for.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/binding-to-json-xml-handling-collections.html

Comment: Now I have another problem. When I want to send a request having single element array I have to do this way: 
"addresses" :{
  "address":{
    "city" : "Warszawa",
    "country" : "Polska",
    "street" : "Testowa 1A",
    }
   }. Serialization looks correct: "addresses": [   {
      "street": "Testowa 1A",
      "city": "Warszawa",
      "country": "Polska"
   }]